# How to bind an element from a list<> to an object (in this case a rectangle) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, list, data-binding, element

I have created the following list:

```
private List<CounterElementViewModel> _counterElement = new List<CounterElementViewModel>();

public List<CounterElementViewModel> CounterElement
{
    get { return _counterElement; }
    set { _counterElement = value; }
}
```

I have created 30 rectangles. Each of the rectangles should be a "CounterElementViewModel", therefore I have a list which includes 30 "CounterElementViewModel".

I have tried to bind each element of the list to one of the 30 rectangles:

```
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[29]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[28]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[27]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[26]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[25]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[24]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[23]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[22]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[21]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[20]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[19]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[18]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[17]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[16]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[15]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[14]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[13]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[12]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[11]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[10]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[9]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[8]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[7]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[6]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[5]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[4]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[3]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[2]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[1]}"/>
<local:CounterElementView DataContext="{Binding CounterElement[0]}"/>
```

Each rectangle should change its color depending on the data, but at the moment nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not enough context to reproduce the issue and answer the question. Can you make a complete example please?

Comment: I only want to know if my syntax to bind an element of a list is correct --> {Binding ListName[index]}

Comment: hi, you are a bit wrong in the method : your <local:CounterElementView must be an ItemControl binded to an observablecollection that contains your viewmodel. <Binding ListName[index]> can work but it is bad. With the provided code we don't know about the - DataContext="{Binding CounterElement - if it works and also local:CounterElementView ? is it well done ? - can't help more

Comment: It looks good. Try to debug element using DataContextChanged Event you will see what you is binding  in runtime.